# Why is no map function for dataframe in pyspark while the spark equivalent has it?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Currently working on PySpark. There is no map function on `DataFrame`, and one has to go to `RDD` for `map` function. In Scala there is a `map` on `DataFrame`, is there any reason for this?

Comment: `df.map(lambda x: x)` should give you a PythonRDD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Dataset.map` is not part of the `DataFrame` (`Dataset[Row]`) API. It transforms strongly typed `Dataset[T]` into strongly typed `Dataset[U]`:

```
def map[U](func: (T) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
```

and there is simply no place for Python in the strongly typed `Dataset` world. In general, `Datasets` are native JVM objects (unlike `RDD` it has not Python specific implementation) which depend heavily on rich Scala type system (even Java API is severely limited). Even if Python implemented some variant of the `Encoder` API, data would still have to be converted to `RDD` for computations.

In contrast Python implements its own `map` like mechanism with vectorized udfs, which should be released in Spark 2.3. It is focused on high performance serde implementation coupled with Pandas API.

That includes both typical `udfs` (in particular `SCALAR` and `SCALAR_ITER` variants) as well as map-like variants - `GROUPED_MAP` and `MAP_ITER` applied through `GroupedData.apply` and `DataFrame.mapInPandas` (Spark >= 3.0.0) respectively.